# Was Rami Malek singing or lipsyncing?

Tags: sound-effects, acting, bohemian-rhapsody

In *Bohemian Rhapsody* Rami Malek played Freddie Mercury from Queen. In the scenes where his character was singing, was the actor really singing with his voice, or only lipsyncing to recordings of Freddie Mercury?

Comment: It's worth noting that in almost all movies with singing, the actors are _always_ lip syncing, or at least, audio from the studio is dubbed in afterward. This is due to how movies are produced, although there is the occasional example where they use the actual audio from the actors' performances (e.g., the 2012 version of _Les Miserables_).

Comment: @ApologizeandreinstateMonica I am aware that movies in Hollywood usually record all dialog, not just singing later int the studio and dub it over whatever was recorded on the set.

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by "not just singing it later". My point was that the song has already been recorded in the studio by the time they go to film. Then, the actor really does sing while he acts (sometimes they lip sync, but usually they actually sing), but he sings along to the pre-recorded track. Then the pre-recorded track is used in the actual film. This isn't always the case, though, like in the example of _Les Miserables_.

Comment: @FireSaraChipps I mean that in Hollywood it is not just singing that is later changed in the final audio for the movie, dialog is usually also recorder again in studio

Comment: I'm aware of that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a combination of Rami Malek's voice, that of Freddie Mercury, and of [Marc Martel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marc_Martel):

Even though Malek was singing, he still needed to lip-sync to Mercury's recordings, so they could overdub his voice where necessary.

[Here](https://www.bustle.com/p/does-rami-malek-really-sing-in-bohemian-rhapsody-heres-how-freddie-mercurys-legendary-voice-was-recreated-12800650)'s an article about the process.